# jQuery - dropdown show/hide

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I'm trying to figure out a clean way of displaying a dropdown and making it go away when leaving. It sounds like a piece of cake but it's not because of the ul/li hierarchy.

Here is the menu structure:

```
<li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
<a href="<link>">TEST</a>
<ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
<a href="<link>">TEST</a>
</ul>
</li>
```

by default, .submenu is set to display:none

I use the following jquery:

```
$( ".has-submenu" ).hover(function() 
    {
       $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
    });
$( ".submenu" ).mouseout(function() 
    {
       $(this).delay(800).fadeOut(100);
    });
```

When I go over .has-submenu, the second div shows up but when I move away, the div disappears and then show up again because when leaving .submenu, I also hit .has-menu along the way.

Is there a way to avoid hitting the primary div on my way out to reach the desired effect?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `<a>` directly inside the `<ul>`. Since you are making use of the `hover` event, you can achieve this in CSS itself. This code is scalable as well, when you have more UL and LIs, while if you want a fade effect, you can use `transition` too.

```css
ul li ul {display: none;}
ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**With Animation**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #ccf;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-submenu navigation-link">
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu="">
      <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Praveen's answer is great and I like it for it's stylistic simplicity. An alternative approach I have used is to put the dropdown box inside a DIV, and call a function onblur or onchange to have it disappear when I am done using it.

Comment: @OverlordvI We can completely avoid the JavaScript. That's what my idea was.

Comment: I like it! I am going to use your code for some of my own projects.

Comment: @OverlordvI It costs me your friendship. If that's okay with you! `:)` There's no free lunch mate. `:D`

Comment: I love that solution, I thought I couldn't avoid JS, thanks a lot Praveen!

Comment: @user3638239 Why can't you avoid JS?

Comment: Praveen, I suppose my ignorance pushed me to investigate a JS based solution but you proved it was possible to do otherwise so that's great !:)

Comment: That's nice... `:)`